# Lua: substrings

Tags: regex, string, lua, substring, lua-patterns

I have a string which can be of any characters. I like to extract only the part between two exclamation marks or *before* the first or *after* the last one:

```
str = "what)ever!when(ver!time!is!mo/ey"

function getStrPart(str,n) -- return a substring
  return str:sub(...) or nil
end

getStrPart(str,0) -- return "what)ever"  -- string until the first !
getStrPart(str,1) -- return "when(ver"   --  between first and second !
getStrPart(str,2) -- return "time"
getStrPart(str,3) -- return "is"
getStrPart(str,4) -- return "mo/ey"
getStrPart(str,5) -- return nil    -- for all n less 0 or > 4 (no of the !)
```

If the string contains no `!`

```
str = "whatever"
```

then the function should return nil

Comment: thanks, works fine. Give it as an answer, please

Comment: @Herbert: He won't. He unfortunately believes that easy questions should be answered in comments, so that the Lua tag's list of "unanswered" questions is utterly useless for finding questions that are actually unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getStrPart(str,n) -- return a substring
  if n>=0 then
    return (
      str:gsub("!.*", "%0!")
         :gsub("[^!]*!", "", n)
         :match("^([^!]*)!")
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `getStrPart` function is going to be highly inefficient. Every time you call it, you have to search through the whole string. It would be much better to just return a table containing all of the "string parts" that you index.

Also, Lua uses 1-based indices, so you should stick to that too.

```
function get_string_parts(str)
  local ret = {}
  for match in str:gmatch("[^!]") do
    if(#match == #str) then --No `!` found in string.
      return ret
    end
    ret[#ret + 1] = match
  end
  return ret
end
```

Comment: You are right but in my special case the other solution makes more sense. However, I'll use your one in another situation. Thanks